# fullCalendar: Extra week displayed after September

Tags: fullcalendar

I see that using v2.1.1 there is an extra week displayed after September - so the first 10 days of October are displayed there.

Examples:

- can be seen right now on the home page of http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
- And also at: http://jsfiddle.net/dLsnqomc/
- And screen cap below...

Code:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
```

Any idea how to remove the superfluous last week (October 5-11)?

Thanks
[image: Sample of extra week]

Comment: You should look at February 2015.  It would appear the default setup always shows 6 rows of 7 days.  You may want to look at the display options: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/fixedWeekCount/

Comment: Thats great - thanks. I wonder someone would want 6 weeks as default??
anyway - thanks. if you answer this as an answer i will check it off.

Comment: @kneidels people want 6 weeks as default to keep a standard/fixed layout.

Comment: solution from @FurukT worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/54307961/14828354

Answer (score 9):

the solution worked for me is; adding the option

`fixedWeekCount: false`,

to config properties of ui-calendar

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple places you could look. It sounds like the issue may have been resolved by setting a value for [fixedWeekCount](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/fixedWeekCount/) (indicated in the comments), but you may also want to take a look at [weekMode](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekMode/):

> ```
> 'fixed'
> ```
>
> The calendar will always be 6 weeks tall. The height will always be the same, as determined by height, contentHeight, or
>   aspectRatio.
>
> Use fixedWeekCount as true instead.
>
> ```
> 'liquid'
> ```
>
> The calendar will have either 4, 5, or 6 weeks, depending on the month. The height of the weeks will stretch to fill the
>   available height, as determined by height, contentHeight, or
>   aspectRatio.
>
> Use fixedWeekCount as false instead.
>
> ```
> 'variable'
> ```
>
> The calendar will have either 4, 5, or 6 weeks, depending on the month. Each week will have the same constant height,
>   meaning the calendar’s height will change month-to-month.
>
> Use height as "auto" and fixedWeekCount as false instead.

Comment: [weekMode](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekMode/) has been deprecated as of V3